# DjangoにてRedisをフェイルオーバーしたい

Tags: python, django, redis

DjangoにてRedisをフェイルオーバーしたいのですが、その具体的な方法が分かりません…。

現状では下記のように設定しております

- Redisをセッションバックエンドとして指定
- Redisのサーバーを二つ用意し、マスタスレーブ構成にする。
- SentinnelにてRedisはマスタに障害が発生した際にはスレーブがマスタに自動昇格

settings.pyは以下のように設定しております

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION':[
            "127.0.0.1",
            "IPofSlave"
        ],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'PASSWORD': "xxxxxxxx",
            'DB': 0,
        }
    }
}
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS = "default"
```

Djangoは基本的にはマスタのみを使い、マスタに障害が発生した際にはスレーブに接続が行くようにしたいのですが、その具体的な方法が分かりません…。

どなたかご存知であればご教示いただけますでしょうか。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

Django標準の `django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache` ではなく、 `django-redis` 及び `redis-py-cluster` というライブラリを組み合わせることで可能なようです。

[django-redis documentation](http://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/)

手元では試せていませんが、Redisクラスタを構築出来た例がIssueにコメントされています。

> ```
>   'default': {
>     'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
>     'LOCATION': 'redis://XXX.YYY.ZZZ.cache.amazonaws.com/0',
>     'OPTIONS': {
>       'REDIS_CLIENT_CLASS': 'rediscluster.RedisCluster',
>       'CONNECTION_POOL_CLASS': 'rediscluster.connection.ClusterConnectionPool',
>       'CONNECTION_POOL_KWARGS': {
>         'skip_full_coverage_check': True # AWS ElasticCache has disabled CONFIG commands
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> [Redis Cluster support. · Issue #208 · niwinz/django-redis](https://github.com/niwinz/django-redis/issues/208)